# How could you automate downloading and installing OS X applications?

Tags: macos

[iusethis.com](http://osx.iusethis.com) redirects URLs like `http://osx.iusethis.com/app/download/appname` to download links, and you could `curl` [MacUpdate](http://www.macupdate.com/) pages for direct download links. Are there any more complete or reliable sources for download links?

How could you automate extracting different types of archives or running installers? [DropZone](http://aptonic.com/features.php) comes with a script that accepts dmg or zip files as input and moves application bundles inside them to `/Applications/`. Does anyone know a similar script that would work with installers or more file types?

Comment: I keep getting a HTTP 404, Server Not Found

Comment: @Luke I edited the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up hacking together this shell script, but stopped maintaining it since many of the download links at iusethis.org are no longer valid and more applications are now distributed through the App Store. I'm leaving it here for the record anyway.

```
#!/bin/bash

export uuid1=$(uuidgen) uuid2=$(uuidgen)
export tmp1=/tmp/autoapp$uuid1 tmp2=/tmp/autoapp$uuid2
mkdir -p $tmp1 $tmp2

shopt -s nullglob
IFS=$'\n'

trap 'onexit &' EXIT
onexit() {
  for mp in $tmp1/mountpoint-*; do
    hdiutil detach -quiet -force $mp
  done
  rm -rf /tmp/autoapp$uuid1 /tmp/autoapp$uuid2
}

app() {
  basename="$(basename "$1")"
  ditto "$1" "/Applications/$basename" 2> /dev/null
  echo "Copied $basename to /Applications/"
}

prefpane() {
  basename="$(basename "$1")"
  ditto "$1" ~/"Library/PreferencePanes/$basename" 2> /dev/null
  echo "Copied $basename to PreferencePanes/"
}

wdgt() {
  basename="$(basename "$1")"
  ditto "$1" ~/"Library/Widgets/$basename" 2> /dev/null
  echo "Copied $basename to Widgets/" 
}

pkg() {
  basename="$(basename "$1")"
  sudo installer -pkg "$1" -target /
  if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    read -n 1 -p "Open $basename (y/n)? " answer
    echo
    [[ "$aswer" == y ]] && open "$f" && exit 1
  fi
}

dmg() {
  mp=$tmp1/mountpoint-$(uuidgen)
  basename="$(basename "$1")"
  echo "Mounting $basename"
  yes | hdiutil attach -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint $mp "$1" > /dev/null
  getfound "$mp" && exit
  echo "Couldn't find an application or package inside $basename"
  exit 1
}

gettmp() {
  getfound $tmp2 && exit

  found="$(find $tmp2 -depth 1 -name "*.dmg" -print0 2> /dev/null |
  xargs -0 du -s | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -f 2)"
  [[ -n "$found" ]] && dmg "$found" && exit

  echo "Couldn't find an application or package"
}

getfound() {
  found="$(find "$1" -maxdepth 2 -name "*.app" -print0\
  -o -name "*.prefPane" -print0 -o -name "*.pkg" -print0\
  -o -name "*.mpkg" -print0 2> /dev/null |
  xargs -0 du -s | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -f 2)"
  if [[ "$found" == *.app ]]; then
    app "$found"
    exit
  elif [[ "$found" == *.prefPane ]]; then
    prefpane "$found"
    exit
  elif [[ "$found" == *.wdgt ]]; then
    wdgt "$found"
    exit
  elif [[ "$found" == *.safariextz ]]; then
    open "$found" && exit
  elif [[ "$found" == *.pkg || "$found" == *.mpkg ]]; then
    pkg "$found"
    exit
  fi
  exit 1
}

untradedouble() {
  echo -n "$1" | ruby -e 'require "CGI"
  x = $<.read
  if x =~ /^http:\/\/.*?tradedoubler.com.*?&url=(.+)/
    print CGI.unescape($1)
  else
    print x
  end'
}

[[ $# == 0 ]] && exit
[[ "$1" == "-h" || "$1" == "--help" || "$1" == "-help" ]] && exit

if [[ -e "$@" ]]; then
  [[ -e "$@" ]] && appfile="$@" || exit
elif [[ "$@" =~ "/" || "$@" =~ "." ]]; then
    echo "The file $@ does not exist"
    exit 1
else
  download=true
fi

if [[ $download ]]; then
  app="$@"
  app2="$(echo "$app" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's|[^a-z0-9\-]||g')"
  iut=http://osx.iusethis.com/app/download/
  head="$(curl --head --max-time 5 -s -w "%{url_effective}\n" -L "$iut$app2")"
  ok="$(echo "$head" | grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23]..")"
  redirect="$(echo "$head" | tail -n 1 | tr -d '\n')"
  bytes=$(echo "$head" | sed -n 's|Content-Length: ||p' |
  tail -n 1 | tr -d '\r')
  if [[ -z "$redirect" || -z "$ok" ]]; then
    read -n 1 -p "Couldn't find $app. Search with Google (y/n)? " answer
    echo
    google="http://www.google.com/search?q=mac+application+"
    [[ $answer =~ [y|Y] ]] && open "$google$app2"
    exit
  fi
  ext="${redirect##*.}"
  exts=" zip gz rar mpkg dmg safariextz prefPane "
  if [[ "$exts" != *" $ext "* || "$bytes" -le 5000 ]]; then
    redirect="$(untradedouble "$redirect")"
    echo "Redirected to $redirect"
    read -n 1 -p "Open in a browser (y/n)? " answer
    echo
    [[ $answer == "y" || $answer == "Y" ]] && open "$redirect"
    exit
  fi
  appfile="$tmp1/${redirect##*/}"
  echo "Downloading $redirect"
  curl "$redirect" -o "$appfile"
fi

appfile="$(echo -n "$appfile" | sed 's|/$||')"

if [[ "$appfile" == *.app ]]; then
  app "$appfile"
elif [[ "$appfile" == *.prefPane ]]; then
  prefpane "$appfile"
elif [[ "$appfile" == *.wdgt ]]; then
  wdgt "$appfile"
elif [[ "$appfile" == *.safariextz ]]; then
  open "$appfile"
elif [[ "$appfile" == *.zip ]]; then
  unzip -q "$appfile" -d $tmp2
  gettmp
elif [[ "$appfile" == *.tar.gz ]]; then
  tar -xf $appfile -C $tmp2
  gettmp
elif [[ "$appfile" == *.dmg ]]; then
  dmg "$appfile"
elif [[ "$appfile" == *.pkg || "$appfile" == *.mpkg ]]; then
  pkg "$appfile"
else
  echo "Couldn't process $(basename "$appfile")"
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AppFresh. If you enter the applications into your iUseThis profile, you should be able to download them using the semi-automatic download process of that tool. Just select "used but not installed" (or similar) from the sidebar.

---

As you seem interested in automating handling `dmg` files, try something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tempimgfile=$( mktemp img.img) || exit 1
mountpoint=$( mktemp -d img.mnt) || exit 1
curl "$1" > ${tempimgfile} || exit 1
hdiutil attach -mountpoint ${mountpoint} ${tempimgfile} || exit 1
cp -r ${mountpoint}/*.app "/Applications"
hdiutil unmount ${mountpoint}
rm -rf ${mountpoint}
rm -f ${tempimgfile}
```

Use like this:

```
$ ./unpack.sh http://www.panic.com/stattoo/d/Stattoo%201.5.dmg
```

Of course, it only works for installing new applications and doesn't do any error handling, so use at your own risk. But opening `dmg` files isn't the actual challenge -- having a comprehensive database of download locations is.

Comment: And it's almost certainly applescriptable. Google was inconclusive, oddly.

Comment: @tobylane Isn't. At least not 0.8.5 (the latest public preview)

Comment: @Lri There's no standardized format for Mac application downloads, as there is (in a way) for package management software, or e.g. Java's Maven repositories. Therefore there can be no universal solution to this issue (think of the Mariner Software folks that require, or required, you to register for a newsletter before a download. VMware isn't any better). All that's left to do might be to provide better download URLs for iUseThis...

Comment: @Lri Who doesn't? And that last part is more or less solved (although not as stand-alone utility, AFAIK).

Comment: @lri You can copy it out of something like contents/macos/archive.tgz, but that only works for stsndalone programs that don't need to ask for credentials.

Comment: @Lri It's easy to automate downloading, mounting, copying contents, unmounting and removal of `dmg` files (at least those without license attached). That's *really* not the hard part.

Comment: @Lri Only added it because you mentioned `dmgs` in reply to @tobylane. I still think the AppFresh folks do the right thing with downloads -- it's just about the quality of the application database now. As I wrote in the fourth comment, there's no way to get that in a standardized format.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple other options for automating the installation of `.dmg` packages:

1. [sprout-wrap](https://github.com/pivotal-sprout/sprout-wrap)
2. [soloist](https://github.com/mkocher/soloist) + [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/)
3. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) + [Casks](http://caskroom.io/)

### Soloist + sprout-wrap Chef Cookbooks

The first two options allow you to utilize [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) recipes to automate the installation of software onto a Mac (or other OS).  The [sprout-wrap](https://github.com/pivotal-sprout/sprout-wrap) project from Pivotal Labs is a collection of cookbooks and recipes that provide software installation recipes for Mac OS X.  [Soloist](https://github.com/mkocher/soloist) is a [Ruby gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem/) that makes it extremely easy to run [`chef-solo`](https://docs.chef.io/chef_solo.html) by providing a single file to contain the `run_list` of cookbooks/recipes to run and `attributes` (like variables) that the recipes use.

The [homebrew cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/homebrew/blob/master/providers/cask.rb) has a `homebrew_cask` provider that the [sprout-osx-apps cookbook](https://github.com/pivotal-sprout/sprout-osx-apps) and [sprout-osx-base::homebrew recipe](https://github.com/pivotal-sprout/sprout-base/blob/master/recipes/homebrew.rb) use to install homebrew casks via `brew cask install`.  To use the `sprout-osx-base::homebrew` recipe, simply add the names of casks to install to your node attributes under `node[:sprout][:homebrew][:casks]` [in your soloistrc like in this example](https://github.com/pivotal-sprout/sprout-wrap/blob/master/soloistrc#L86).

To keep things simple, just check out the [README for sprout-wrap](https://github.com/pivotal-sprout/sprout-wrap) and follow the installation steps.  If you want to customize your `soloistrc` file to choose what to install, you can check out [Pivotal's example here](https://github.com/pivotal-sprout/sprout-wrap/blob/master/soloistrc) or look at my [more advanced & customized version here](https://github.com/trinitronx/sprout-wrap/blob/gloo-develop/soloistrc).

If you want an even easier way to get started, check out [SoloWizard](http://www.solowizard.com/).  Which will generate an auto-install bootstrap script for you to get started with.

### Homebrew Casks

If you're not looking for anything as customizable or think Chef/soloist are too complicated... Just start with [Homebrew Casks](http://caskroom.io/) and check if there is an already existing cask formula for your package with `brew cask search`.